# Make library comes from maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, response, spring-restcontroller

Hello guys I clone one project from github This project in spring boot.
When I import all library ResponseEntity.ok dosn't see from right place. When I put over imported path in class I see it comes from wrong directory. But When I create new project there is comes from right place. I've got question How I can figure it out call from right place instead of coming from wrong place. Thank you guys in advance

```
    @GetMapping(value = "get")
    public ResponseEntity<List<BssClient>> get(){
//        cardStatement.CardStatement()
        List<BssClient> list = dataBase.findAllBssClient();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(list);
    }
```

[image]

[image]

**My pom file is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>uz.ofb.tir-to-sv</groupId>
    <artifactId>tir-to-sv</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>tir-to-sv</name>
    <description>ТИР и SV-GATE</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/oracle/ojdbc6 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/jaxb2-maven-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**The right place of class path is**

This is from different classes and from different project.

[image]

**The question How to make library comes from maven instead of coming from java library. After clone new project from github.**

Answer (score 2):

@Jahongir `ResponseEntity class` is a part of `spring web dependency` So, you don't need to add `httpClient` to get this class.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This won't help me I know what part of this ResponseEntity class .